# Put list of object into Infinispan cache and search by them

Tags: caching, search, infinispan

I put the list of objects into cache and I need to do select by its property values as:

```
        Cache<Object, Object> cache = cacheManager.getCache(searchResultName);
    assertThat(cache, is(notNullValue()));


    Container container = new Container();

    List<Detail> details = Lists.newArrayList();

    details.add(new Detail(2, "two"));
    details.add(new Detail(2, "two"));
    details.add(new Detail(3, "three"));
    details.add(new Detail(3, "three"));
    details.add(new Detail(3, "three"));
    details.add(new Detail(5, "five"));
    details.add(new Detail(5, "five"));
    details.add(new Detail(5, "five"));
    details.add(new Detail(5, "five"));
    details.add(new Detail(5, "five"));


    cache.put("q", details);

    QueryFactory queryFactory = org.infinispan.query.Search.getQueryFactory(cache);
    org.infinispan.query.dsl.QueryBuilder queryBuilder = queryFactory.from(Detail.class)
            .having("number").eq(5);
    details = queryBuilder.build().list();
    assertThat(details.size(), is(5));

@Indexed
class Container {

    @IndexedEmbedded
    private List<Detail> details;

    public List<Detail> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(List<Detail> details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}


@Indexed
class Detail {

    @Field
    private int number;

    private String text;

    public Detail(int number, String text) {
        this.number = number;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

My code returns
Expected: is <5>
     but: was <0>

I tried to use a POJO as container (wiht property List and get|set methods). 
In this case I receive my container with all details, without any selection.

Help, pls!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the

```
cache.put("q", details);
```

You are adding a list-of-details as the value. The query you use later on searches for Details as values (`.from(Details.class)`). Maybe you intended to store

```
container.setDetails(details);
cache.put("q", container);
```

and then the query would start with `qf.from(Container.class)`, selecting the embedded objects. However note that this does not scale very well; Infinispan does not decompose the object, it would store it as a single big chunk under the key `q`.

Comment: I researched such way. Infinispan returns one Container with all details, without any selection.

Comment: You need to use projection: http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#projections